# Get the icon of a Foursquare category from its ID

Tags: foursquare

thanks in advance for your time.

I would like to know how can I get the corresponding image of a `Foursquare` category programmatically by passing the `Foursquare` *category ID*.

I have read the `API` documents and so far have not been able to find a solution for this.

A `JSON` url would be great, but a `OAuth` app can work as well.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 8):

**According to the official docs:**
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/venues/categories

> Pieces needed to construct category icons at various sizes. Combine prefix with a size (32, 44, 64, and 88 are available) and suffix, e.g. https://foursquare.com/img/categories/food/default_64.png. To get an image with a gray background, use bg_ before the size, e.g. https://foursquare.com/img/categories_v2/food/icecream_bg_32.png.

**Sample:**

```
{
   "categories":[
      {
         "id":"4bf58dd8d48988d163941735",
         "name":"Park",
         "pluralName":"Parks",
         "shortName":"Park",
         "icon":{
            "prefix":"https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/parks_outdoors/park_",
            "suffix":".png"
         },
         "primary":true
      }
   ]
}
```

**Output without background (size: 64):**

```
https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/parks_outdoors/park_64.png
```

**With background (size 88):**

```
https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/parks_outdoors/park_bg_88.png
```

Answer (score 2):

In the [**official documentation**](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/) you can't find any API method to retrieve category by id

**Venue Categories**

> https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/categories
>
> Returns a hierarchical list of categories applied to venues.

In fact this note is particular interesting:

> When designing client applications, please download this list only
>   once per session, but also avoid caching this data for longer than a
>   week to avoid stale information.

**The Response fields**

> An array of categories containing sub- and sub-sub- categories. Each
>   top-level category contains a id, name, pluralName, icon, and
>   categories (an array of child categories).

Anywawy just to achieve your task, from a JSON retrived by https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=/venues/categories, you can do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/InferOn/u8q6u/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

  <script>
    // sample categories JSON 
    var p = {
      meta: {
        code: 200
      },
      notifications: [
        {
          type: "notificationTray",
          item: {
            unreadCount: 0
          }
        }
      ],
      response: {
        categories: [
          {
            id: "4fceea171983d5d06c3e9823",
            name: "Acquario",
            pluralName: "Acquari",
            shortName: "Acquario",
            icon: {
              prefix: "https://ss1.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/aquarium_",
              suffix: ".png"
            },
            categories: [
              {
                id: "4bf58dd8d48988d134941735",
                name: "Studio di danza",
                pluralName: "Studi di danza",
                shortName: "Studio di danza",
                icon: {
                  prefix: "https://ss1.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/performingarts_dancestudio_",
                  suffix: ".png"
                }
              },
              {
                id: "4bf58dd8d48988d135941735",
                name: "Teatro indie",
                pluralName: "Teatri con produttori indipendenti",
                shortName: "Produttore indipendente",
                icon: {
                  prefix: "https://ss1.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/performingarts_indieoffbroadway_",
                  suffix: ".png"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            id: "4bf58dd8d48988d1e1931735",
            name: "Sala Giochi",
            pluralName: "Sale Giochi",
            shortName: "Sala Giochi",
            icon: {
              prefix: "https://ss1.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/arts_entertainment/arcade_",
              suffix: ".png"
            },
            categories: []
          }
        ]
      }
    }

    function customFilter(object) {
      if (object.hasOwnProperty('id') && object["id"] == '4bf58dd8d48988d134941735')
        return object;

      for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(object).length; i++) {
        if (typeof object[Object.keys(object)[i]] == "object") {
          o = customFilter(object[Object.keys(object)[i]]);
          if (o != null)
            return o;
        }
      }

      return null;
    }

    var result = customFilter(p);

    alert(result['icon']['prefix'] + result['icon']['suffix']);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```